# How can I check user privileges in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've checked the documentation for managing user privileges (https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/how-to-guides/manage-user-privileges) and I've created a new user:

```
CREATE USER `james@skyfalllodge.co.uk` IDENTIFIED BY '007';
```

And I've added the privileges:

```
GRANT MATCH, MERGE, CREATE, DELETE, REMOVE, SET TO `james@skyfalllodge.co.uk`
```

How can I check if the privileges are assign? Do I need to try to run queries using `MATCH, MERGE, CREATE, DELETE, REMOVE` to test it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that you are looking for is

```
SHOW PRIVILEGES FOR `james@skyfalllodge.co.uk`
```

P.S. The query that you have listed (GRANT MATCH, MERGE, CREATE, DELETE, REMOVE SET TO `james@skyfalllodge.co.uk`) has a typo. You are missing a comma after remove. Please fix this.